# python, selectively pop values from one dictionary into another using comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

How do I convert this function here into a dictionary comprehension? is it possible?

```
info['dict1'] = {}
dict2 = {'one': 1}

for x in ['one', 'two']:
    info['dict1'].update({x:dict2.pop(x, None)})
```

Here is what I tried it didn't work very well, nothing seem to happen. info stays empty:

```
(info['dict1'].update({x:dict2.pop(x)}) for x in ['one', 'two'])
```

The print output shows that info stays empty ... `{'dict1': {}}`

Comment: Do you mean "dictionary comprehension"?

Comment: Is the last line of your code (`info = {'dict1': {}`) supposed to be at the beginning?

Comment: ah no that just the print output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
info['dict1'] = {x: dict2.pop(x, None) for x in ['one', 'two']}
```

Don't use comprehensions for side effects; they produce a list, set or dictionary first and foremost. In the code above, a *new* dictionary object for `info['dict1']` is produced by a dictionary comprehension.

If you *have* to update an existing dictionary, use `dict.update()` with a generator expression producing key-value pairs:

```
info['dict1'].update((x, dict2.pop(x, None)) for x in ['one', 'two'])
```

Comment: yes, but this is creating a new dictionary into the dict1 key, where as I wanted the value added to the current empty dict in dict1

Comment: @user1539348: but it was empty *anyway*, so you may as well replace it.

Comment: I meant that in the case where the dictionary was not empty and I wanted it to be updated. But yes your answer would work if I didn't care and it was empty.

Comment: Thanks! The generator is what I was looking for. I tried doing something similiar but it failed miserably, probably because of my syntax somewhere. kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can create `info` with dict with the key and use a dict comp ad the value.

```
dict2 = {'one': 1}
info = {'dict1': {x: dict2.pop(x, None) for x in ['one', 'two']} }
print(info)
```